# Matlab's Inline function in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, inline

In Matlab, we can do

```
x = -10:.1:10;
f = inline('normpdf(x,3,2) + normpdf(x,-5,1)','x');
t = plot(x,f(x))
```

Do we have a similar function like `inline` in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the python equivalent of "Inline" would be lambda

```
 Matlab:
 f = inline('normpdf(x,3,2) + normpdf(x,-5,1)','x');

 python:
 f = lambda x : normpdf(x,3,2) + normpdf(x,-5,1)
 # Assuming that normpdf is defined and in scope ;-)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in iPython notebook (and maybe Enthought Canopy?), you can set inline using the "magic function"

```
% pylab inline
```

You must restart the kernel for it to take effect (at least for iPython notebook versions anterior to 2.0)

Comment: I edited, you only need one % sign. You need only type this line in a cell of the notebook, and execute the cell. This must be done before you import pylab or matplotlib.

Comment: In view of the other replies, this inline might not be the one you were asking for...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`, which is a dangerous function (see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html):

```
from numpy import *
x = np.arange(0, pi, 0.1)
f = eval('sin') # fill in any function
y = f(x)
```

or like assuming that the variable in your finction is always referred to as x

```
from numpy import *
x = np.arange(0, pi, 0.1)
y = eval('sin(x)')
```

Comment: eval is so risky - especially if you are asking for input from the user !

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 you're right. I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

that isn´t the same, because lambda does other thing, i just want replace values of my variable F in GRAD but using 'inline', this code is of matlab:

```
F= 3*X**2+2*X*Y+4*(Y-2)**2  
GRAD= inline([diff(F,X), diff(F,Y)])
```